# Advices to create a data set from dictionnary's screenshot

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning, image-preprocessing

I have six thousand screenshots like the one below. I would like to create a date set to do some deep learning. My goal in the end is to create the next word prediction using only my own word data set.
(For exemple, I found this : [Next word prediction](https://towardsdatascience.com/next-word-prediction-with-nlp-and-deep-learning-48b9fe0a17bf))

So for the first step, I would like to extract the english word of the photo (here it's reckless). Do you think I can code something to do it for me because it might be "reckless" to write them down six thousand time.

I have ubuntu 20/windows 10
I code a lot with python and I tried in the past Java, C and Ocaml for a semester.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: If you goal is to have a word data set, there are plenty of other easier way to have some. You can see an article bout word prediction here : https://towardsdatascience.com/next-word-prediction-with-nlp-and-deep-learning-48b9fe0a17bf; some other link to words files here : https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

Comment: Hi Malo, I would like to use my own words please. I've been selecting words I like since 3 years.

Comment: ok fine. But I think to make next word prediction you will also need to have some texts, not only words. Have you already some ?

Comment: I do but a few, about 5 sentences per word. But I was thinking maybe I can use a data set to predict which of my word is relevant according to a text (in practice it's a conversation).

Answer (score 0):

For the word extraction from the image you can use one of the OCR such as [Tesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract)
then try to clean the extracted dataset in order to use it to train the model